# BMP2AVI program in matlab

Tags: matlab, bmp

HI
I wrote a program that use to work (swear to god) and has stopped from working. this code takes a series of BMPs and convert them into avi file. this is the code:

```
path4avi='C:/FadeOutMask/'; %dont forget the '/' in the end of the path
pathOfFrames='C:/FadeOutMask/';
NumberOfFiles=1;
NumberOfFrames=10;

%1:1:(NumberOfFiles)
for i=0:1:(NumberOfFiles-1)
FileName=strcat(path4avi,'FadeMaskAsael',int2str(i),'.avi') %the generated file
aviobj = avifile(FileName,'compression','None'); 
aviobj.fps=10;

    for j=0:1:(NumberOfFrames-1)
    Frame=strcat(pathOfFrames,'MaskFade',int2str(i*10+j),'.bmp') %not a good name for thedirectory
    [Fa,map]=imread(Frame);
    imshow(Fa,map);
    F=getframe();
    aviobj=addframe(aviobj,F)
    end
aviobj=close(aviobj);
end
```

And this is the error I get:

```
??? Error using ==> checkDisplayRange at 22
HIGH must be greater than LOW.

Error in ==> imageDisplayValidateParams at 57
common_args.DisplayRange = checkDisplayRange(common_args.DisplayRange,mfilename);

Error in ==> imageDisplayParseInputs at 79
common_args = imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);

Error in ==> imshow at 199
  [common_args,specific_args] = ...

Error in ==> ConverterDosenWorkd at 19
    imshow(Fa,map);
```

for some reason I cant put it as code segments. sorry

thank you

Ariel

Comment: You can select code and click the code button on the toolbar.

Comment: if I remove the map form imread and the imshow it works.. but it did't use to work without the map. I have no idea how this could change.

Answer (score 0):

Are the BMP images indexed?  I think the `map` parameter only applies to images with indexed color maps.

Comment: I don't know. How do i check it? is there a matlab\python operation that indexes the images?

Comment: I don't do much image processing, but my understanding is that indexing refers to a way of storing the color data.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color for more information.  I have no idea if `imread` will have a problem if you ask for a `map` parameter when the file doesn't have one.  I guess you could create an image file with Paint or the GIMP or something and verify that `imread` behaves like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am able to reproduce the error that you get is when `map` is a two-element vector where the first element is greater than the second. Note first that the function [IMSHOW](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imshow.html) can be called with the following syntax:

```
imshow(I,[low high]);
```

In which `I` is a grayscale image and `low` and `high` specify the display range for the pixel intensities. The extra argument is ignored when `I` is an RGB image, but even then the value of `high` must be greater than the value of `low` or an error is thrown (the one you see above).

What's confusing is why `map` would be a two-element vector. When loading an image with [IMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html), the `map` output will either be empty (if the image is not an indexed image) or it will be an N-by-3 color map. I can't think of a situation where the built-in [IMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html)  would return a `map` argument with just 2 elements.

Based on the fact that you said it *was* working, and now suddenly isn't, I would suggest first checking to see if you have inadvertently created an m-file somewhere with the name `imread`. Doing so could cause that new `imread` function to be called instead of the built-in one, giving you different outputs than you expect.